# How do I resolve a 'Conflicting configuration arguments' warning when creating an EC2 instance with Crossplane?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, infrastructure-as-code, crossplane

When I apply this EC2 manifest:

```
apiVersion: ec2.aws.upbound.io/v1beta1
kind: Instance
metadata:
  name: test15
spec:
  forProvider:
    region: us-west-2
    ami: ami-0ab193018f3e9351b  #Amazon Linux 2023 AMI (64-bit (x86)) 
    instanceType: t2.micro
    creditSpecification:
      - cpuCredits: unlimited
    keyName: first
  providerConfigRef:
    name: aws-provider-config
```

I receive this warning:

```
Message:               observe failed: cannot run refresh: refresh failed: Conflicting configuration arguments: "cpu_options.0.core_count": conflicts with cpu_core_count
Conflicting configuration arguments: "cpu_options.0.threads_per_core": conflicts with cpu_threads_per_core
Conflicting configuration arguments: "cpu_core_count": conflicts with cpu_options.0.core_count
Conflicting configuration arguments: "cpu_threads_per_core": conflicts with cpu_options.0.threads_per_core
```

Here is a [screen capture of the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIwy8.png).
The instance gets created without a name and it becomes not synced

I've changed the `instanceType` but there was no change in behaviour